# calibration and liftchart with caret R package

Tags: r, performance, parameters, r-caret

I am comparing various predictive models on a binary classification task using the caret R package with respect to their predictive performance (liftChart) and prediction accuracy (calibration plot). I found the following issues:
1. Sometimes the     lift     function is very very slow when the number of observation is quite big or there are various competing classifiers. In addition I wonder whether it is possible to manually define the cuts of the calibration plot. I have a severe imbalanced model (average probability is 5%) and the calibration plot function assumes evenly spaced cuts.

Comment: Might be an interesting problem to tackle if only there were a reproducible example. Shouldn't be that difficult to construct a test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lift plot does the calculation for every unique probability value (much like an ROC curve), which is why it is slow.

Neither of those options are available right now. You can add two issues to the [github page](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues). I'm fairly swamped right now but those shouldn't be a big deal to change (you could always contribute solutions too).

Max